# Finding out if a Window is being Dragged

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, applescript

I am trying to write a program that requires to know if a window is being dragged (moved around). The catch is that it's not the program's window, but rather any window in the OS (eg. Safari, iTunes, Adium, TextMate, etc.), and what program it belongs to

I was thinking AppleScript would be a potential way to do this, but there doesn't seem to be anyway to know whether it's being dragged.

Any ideas?

Comment: dup. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/853833/how-can-my-app-detect-a-change-to-another-apps-window

Comment: Not necessarily, as that isn't specific to windows being dragged.

Comment: On further thought, I see your point. Still a good place to look for the questioner as it does deal with windows in other applications being moved, and the answer there is fairly in-depth.

Comment: The suggested duplicate was doing it in cocoa, this question is  in applescript.

Answer (score 0):

On window will resize handler or window will move handler.  I'm not sure if those are the exact names but you can find them in the Window section of the Applescript section in the inspect window in Interface Builder.

Comment: I believe they only work for your own application's windows? Please correct me if I'm wrong.