# Observe any Window if it Moved on OSX

Tags: macos

I want to observe any window on OSX if it is moved. I don't own the windows so i can't get to it directly so I think I have to use the Accessibility APIs. I found a solution for the current active Application here: [How can my app detect a change to another app's window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853833/how-can-my-app-detect-a-change-to-another-apps-window) but I can't figure out how I have to modify this that it works for any window which is open. I hope anybody could give me a hint in which direction I have to look.

Comment: Does it make sense to observe window-move events on applications that aren’t currently active? How often do inactive windows move?

Comment: ok right. Is it possible to get notified if the current focused application changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, people usually only want to detect window-move events on focused windows. (As unfocused windows seldom move.) If you want to detect application switches, you can poke into this [sample project by Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/iChatStatusFromApplication/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html) that shows how to update iChat status with the frontmost application’s name. And as you said, there’s already a [solution for an active window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853833).