# How to Use AXObserverAddNotification in Swift?

Tags: swift, macos, accessibility

How I can use AXObserverAddNotification in Swift to detect an UI change?

There's a great answer here in Obj C.

[How can my app detect a change to another app's window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853833/how-can-my-app-detect-a-change-to-another-apps-window)

How to translate the answer to Swift?

The testing code below compiles and runs without an error, but callBack doesn't seem to get executed when I change main window.

```
    func observe(app:pid_t, element:AXUIElement) {
        var observer: AXObserver? = nil
        func callBack(observer: AXObserver?, element: AXUIElement?, notification: CFString, refcon: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
            print("Fired! \(notification)")
        }
        if AXObserverCreate(app, callBack, &observer) == .success {
            print("AXObserverCreate success!")
            if AXObserverAddNotification(observer!, element, kAXMainWindowChangedNotification as CFString, UnsafeMutableRawPointer(Unmanaged.passRetained(self).toOpaque())) == .success {
                print("AXObserverAddNotification success!")
                CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), AXObserverGetRunLoopSource(observer!), .defaultMode)
                print("Watching \(element.value(of:"AXTitle"))")
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

[@kyo-ago](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9762269/kyo-ago) did a great job on encapsulating those C-like swift APIs in his [project](https://github.com/kyo-ago/Automatically-Move-Mouse-Pointer-To-Default-Button-in-a-dialog-box-for-mac/blob/master/Automatically%20Move%20Mouse%20Pointer%20To%20Default%20Button%20in%20a%20dialog%20box%20for%20mac/Applications/Application.swift).